# Init NSDictionary with another NSDictionary but its remains empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm new in iOS development and Objective-C, and i can't solve this problem.
Here is my code:

Heder file:
`@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *featuredProducts;`

Implementation file

```
-(void)findFeaturedProducts {
    __block NSDictionary *value = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
    NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    value = [rawJson JSONValue];
    // then i try this:
    _featuredProducts = value;
    // its not working, so i thy this:
    _featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:value];
    // but it gives the same result, so then i try this:
    _featuredProducts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:value];
    // and this
    _featuredProducts = [value copy];
    NSLog(@"_featuredProducts: %@", _featuredProducts);}];
}
```

But NSLog shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PikyQ.png) all the time

EDITED.

Comment: did you try to NSLog the Value ?

Comment: why are you using __block in `__block NSDictionary *value = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];`

Comment: you probably don't fill value dictionary correctly

Comment: how are you filing the value from the block, its NSDictionary and not MutableDictionary

Comment: how are you setting the value from server

Comment: __block NSDictionary *value = [[NSDictionary alloc]init]; 
value=null

Comment: Probably not being returned anything from the server. Are you 100% sure something is being returned?

Comment: `...filling value from server...` how doest this happen ??

Comment: value is not null, its filling as it should

Comment: i use __block because i fill value in block

Comment: Apparently value is an empty `NSDictionary` at that point in time when `findFeaturedProducts` ist called. To me using `__block` does not make sense here.

Comment: Please share the code were value is being initialized and filled with data.

Comment: It's not empty, i checked it. Edited code.

Comment: do a `NSLog(@"Value: %@", value);`

Comment: I was done it before ask a question, value contains data what i need.

Comment: You need to show the code that populates `value`.  There is a strong suspicion that you are doing it asynchronously and that you don't really understand the implications of doing that.

Comment: Code which populated `value` is in topic, i edited it.

Comment: Confirmed; you don't understand the implications of using asychronous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `retain` to `strong`, you're in 2016 now)

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *featuredProducts;

Try this code

```
-(void)findFeaturedProducts {

NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){

    NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.featuredProducts = [rawJson JSONValue];

    //if previous not help uncomment previous and use next one
    /*
    NSError* unpackJsonError;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    self.featuredProducts = json;*/
    }];
}
```

Note, that this code is asynchronous, and you need to update you table, or view when request will be finished.
some , [MyTable reloadData]

Comment: In this case you cant access this data, you need to transfer the data like this
If you going to another ViewController, you must transfer its data to header property,when another controller is presenting.
NextViewControllerClass *nextVC.featuredProducts = self.featuredProducts.
 
And in `NextViewControllerClass.h` you must specify

`@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *featuredProducts;`

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you are using an asynchronous call to get the dictionary. If you use a synchronous call, make it asynchronous. Your users HATE synchronous calls. If you use an asynchronous call, set the dictionary in the callback of the asynchronous call. It would be very, very, very rare that you would ever use __block.

Comment: So effectively `_featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:nil];`?  I think something might happen in that case?

Comment: I use URLSessionDataTask to fill the dictionary, so i don't see another way to not use __block

Answer (score 0):

Try use code below.
This may help you.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dictTemp copyItems:YES];

NSLog(@"Dict :- %@",dict);
```

Comment: try to print your server response in log to check that response dictionary is null or not.

Comment: It's not null, 'value' dictionary fills by response data as it should.

Comment: can i see screen shot of your server response.

Comment: Try this code.....
`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[dictTemp valueForKey:@"products"] copyItems:YES];

NSLog(@"Dict :- %@",dict);`

Answer (score 0):

`value` is set asynchronously in the `completionHandler` block. Since you try and create a new dictionary and assign it to `featuredProducts` value does outside of the completion handler, you are asking `value` before the network operation has completed and it does not yet have a value.

You need to set `featuredProducts` **inside** the completion handler. I.e. imediately after `value=[rawJson JSONValue];`

Comment: In that case _featuredProducts = {null}

Comment: It will be null if you check its value outside of the completion handler and before the network operation has completed. Remember that the line after the session data task will execute immediately but the network operation will take some time. Typically you will invoke some method inside the completion handler to process the data that has been retrieved

Comment: I checked it inside, same as i checked `value` before (and value was not null, it was filled as it should)

Comment: I can guarantee that you aren't setting the value correctly in the completion handler or you are checking the property before the completion handler has executed. Set a breakpoint on the line inside the completion handler and step through to confirm that value is being set and your property is being set to a new dictionary copy. Also you should use `self.featuredProducts` not `_featuredProducts` unless you have a specific need to bypass the setter/getter

Comment: Also I can't see anywhere where you are executing `[getData resume]` so are you even getting the data from the network?

Comment: It's goes just after request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a block variable i would create a weak reference to self

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error) {
NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
weakSelf.featuredProducts = [rawJson JSONValue];
//if your dict is not initialized try this
weakSelf.featuredProducts =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[rawJson JSONValue]];
    }];
}
```

Comment: You don't even need a weak self. You can safely use self since the block is not captured by the object there is no scope for a retain cycle.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right but still to be safe. `weakSelf.featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[rawJson JSONValue]];`

Comment: `self.featuredProducts` (or `weakSelf.featuredProducts` if you insist), but you don't want the _

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right i forgot a little bit the ObjC sintax sorry